# c++ MessageBox first character or word wrong

Tags: c++, utf-8, messagebox

I've got a really strange problem. My program reads some UTF-8 content from a server into a `char` buffer. Then I convert this `char` buffer to  a `LPWSTR` using the function `MultiByteToWideChar()`. After this I create a thread to display a MessageBox containing the response of the server.

This is my ***edited*** code:

```
function checkMessages()
{
    // some code...

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, &CreateMessageBox, lpszText, 0, NULL);

    // some code...

    delete[] lpszText; // this causes the error!!
}

DWORD WINAPI CreateMessageBox(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    MessageBoxW(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)lpParam,
        L"You received a message!",
        MB_TOPMOST
        );

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the first character or the first word of the MessageBox is changed to any other symbol/s. Sometimes the Message is displayed correctly, sometimes not...

Do you have any ideas what could be the reason for this strange behavior?

***EDIT***:
in the edited code example above I already added the error-generating code line.
Thanks to all commenters which helped me to find the error!

Comment: (also you have a typo in 'recieved')

Comment: @rbm thanks ;-) (edited)

Comment: An obvious problem is that you pass only a pointer to the thread. The pointer points to non-const data that isn't owned by the msgbox thread so the data might be modified by the original thread that created the msgbox thread. BTW: Create a thread to show a messagebox is a really bad pattern. Why do you do that? In a normal GUI program all gui code should be called on the GUI thread (that is usually the main thread). If you want to pass a message from a worker to the gui thread then a good pattern is to use `PostMessage()` from the worker and you can decide on the gui thread how to display it.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I'm trying at the moment with `CreateThread(NULL, 0, CreateMessageBox, lpszText, 0, NULL);` but the behavior seems to persist. My program is a console program. It starts at least one program so it gets hidden behind it. To display a message to the user I create the MessageBox, but if the user wouldn't confirm the MessageBox the console program in the background would stop working till the MessageBox is confirmed...

Comment: @SaschaP So you are basically trying the same, and surprisingly the same thing happens. If you are writing a console program then why do you want to display a messagebox? Your solution isn't only buggy but flawed in design. What happens if your program fires 1000 error messages? You create 1000 threads and 1000 messageboxes? A thread is actually very expensive resource for the OS and users are very annoyed when they have to click 1000 messageboxes.

Comment: @pasztorpisti ok, so I am obviously not able to solve the "pointer-problem"... Can you please help me? I wrote a console program because I'm not familiar enough with C# to create good GUIs. Also there is not really anything to display while the program is running, so there is no need for a GUI in my mind. Furthermore `checkMessages()` is called once every 15 minutes, so there won't be thousands of threads with message boxes.

Comment: If you are going to pass `lpszText` as a pointer to the thread then give the thread ownership of the memory that the pointer is pointing at. Allocate `lpszText` dynamically at runtime and fill it as needed, then pass the pointer to the thread and let the thread free the memory after `MessageBox()` exits. It sounds like the memory that `lpszText` is pointing at is still owned by `checkMessages()` and is being overwritten before `MessageBox()` has a chance to use it.

Comment: It's the `lpszText` pointer. You are passing only a pointer to the thread, but the actual data the pointer points to is at the original location and both threads have access to it. In worst case it's only an array on the stack of the original thread that gets destroyed when the original thread overwrites it or returns. I guess this is why the random overwrite happens but this isn't obvious from the code you've posted. If you have non-fatal error messages (since you can continue) then you should simply print these error messages (or rather warnings) to the stderr.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Thank you very much, I found the error! It was because I called `delete[] lpszText;` some lines after `CreateThread()`. Thank you.

Comment: @SaschaP You are welcome. I think you should redesign the user interface and focus on bugs later. The mixture of console with msgboxes is always a bad design. You should post a question about what kind of user interface would suit your particular kind of program. I'm not sure about the right location for such a question though. It may be a stackexchange forum other than stackoverflow. If you need a gui feedback then a gui app would be a better choice in my opinion. Also: multithreaded programming may be too difficult before you are good in other topics (like pointers and GUI).

Comment: @pasztorpisti yes, you may be right, there is much to do and learn for me, when I have time to I will focus on mentioned topics.

Comment: @pasztorpisti at least I am a student but my program is for other purposes. I hadn't much more learning material than a C++ book and the internet (mainly MSDN) to learn the parts of the language I needed for my programs. So I have no profound knowledge now, but I am very interested in programming and I'm going to start studying informatics in future :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "complete" this question I'll answer it.

as shown in my question-code-sample this part `delete[] lpszText;` caused the error. 
It seems that it clears the variable nearly simultaneous while the created thread tries to access it. I removed the line and everything works fine!

Thanks to the commenters which guided me in the right direction!